# Why does Rails define a controller action when merely a view exists?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller

I just spent a good deal of time trying to debug a controller action that was erroneously marked `protected`. When I commented out the action and Rails didn't respond with `Unknown action` as I'd expected, I became suspicious.

Turns out that having an appropriately named view is enough for Rails to define a controller action. So my two questions are:

1. Why on Earth does Rails do that? To help newbies?
2. Can I keep Rails from doing this with some piece of config?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might not answer all your question, but the Rails Guide on rendering discusses this in the section
[Rendering by Default: Convention Over Configuration in Action](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-by-default-convention-over-configuration-in-action)